# In folders that are under SVN the context menu item "properties" is removed

Tags: svn, explorer

In folders where there is a .svn folder I cannot right click on a file and choose "properties" anymore.
The context menu appears correctly, but the list ends right before where "properties" is supposed to be.
When I delete the .svn folder the item returns again.

I have the latest version of tortoiseSVN installed.
Anyone experienced this? Any ideas why and how to solve this?

Comment: Try to select the folder and press Alt-Return. Does that open the properties dialog?

Comment: yes. it does. So the function itself is still working. It's just the menu item that's dissapeared

Answer (score 2):

Workaround: Select the folder and press `Alt-Return`. That should open the properties dialog.

Comment: Thanks. That is indeed a workaraound. But the question is WHY is this?